# При push'е образа в GitLab registry используя jenkins появляется ошибка: Invalid repository name

Tags: docker, jenkins, gitlab-ci

Если вручную использовать команды например:

```
docker build -t company.domain:5000/root/dockerimages/image:tag .
docker push company.domain:5000/root/dockerimages/image:tag
```

То всё окей. И в gitlab'е мы получаем образы. 
Но если запускаю из jenkins, то получаем ошибку:

```
Invalid repository name (dockerimages/image), only [a-z0-9-_.] are allowed
```

Comment: Проверьте, что версии клиентов на хосте дженкинса и на локальной машине. Есть вероятность, что устаревший клиент на стороне дженкинса не готов к многоуровневым репозиториям (сейчас ему не нравится слэш в названии, судя по всему).

Comment: Скорее всего дело в этом. Действительно большая разница в версиях.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ага

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что все дело в том, что на локальной машине стоит более свежая версия docker-клиента, позволяющая использовать слэши в названии - судя по тексту ошибки, проблема именно в том, что название изображения не проходит валидацию, которая проходит не на сервере.

Comment: Да, действительно. При обновлении docker ошибка исчезла.